# How does one find the solution y(n) from y(n+1)? (System of Difference Equations)

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of differnce equations:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
        Y_1(t+1)\\
        Y_2(t+1)
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    A
    \begin{bmatrix}
        Y_1(t)\\
        Y_2(t)
    \end{bmatrix}
    +
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        G_0
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Where 
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    bk+b & -kb
\end{bmatrix},\quad 0<b<1,k>0
$,
is a real valued constant matrix.

I know the system is autonomous, and that the solution is given by:
$
Y(n)=A^{n-n_0}y_0+\sum_{r=n_0}^{n-1}A^{n-r-1}g(r)
$

Here $y(n_0)=y_0$, and i know that $g(r)=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
G_0
\end{bmatrix}$ so the solution to the given system would be given accordingly:

$
Y(n)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    bk+b & -kb
\end{bmatrix}
^{n-n_0}y_0+\sum_{r=n_0}^{n-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    bk+b & -kb
\end{bmatrix}
^{n-r-1}.\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
G_0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Is this a satisfying solution?

Say that $n_0=0$ which then gives:

$
Y(n)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    bk+b & -kb
\end{bmatrix}
^{n}y_0+\sum_{r=n_0}^{n-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    bk+b & -kb
\end{bmatrix}
^{n-r-1}.\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
G_0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Is it then possible to find $A^n$ by Putzers Algorithm, I have tried myself, but whenever i put in real values for $b,k$ my $A^n$ returns complex numbers in the anti-diagonal.

Or would it be easier to approach the solution by The Jordan Form, or does that only work with homogenous difference equations?

Comment: Are they small complex numbers that you get from Putzer's algorithm? These could just be caused by small roundoff error if some of the eigenvalues of $A$ are complex. In any case you could also use the Jordan form to simplify the powers. But your matrix should actually be diagonalizable anyway: the determinant is $-bk-b$ and the trace is $-bk$ and so you only have a failure of diagonalizability if $-bk-b=(-bk/2)^2$ which cannot be in this case.

Comment: I can figure out how to express $A^n$ by Jordan form, but how to i express $A^{n-n_0}$ or $A^{n-r-1}$ by jordan form?

Comment: They are just different exponents, only the diagonal matrix will change. Also the eigenvalues of A shouldn't be complex because it has a negative determinant, so I have no idea where your issues with Putzer's algorithm are coming from.

Comment: I see, well i guess I have to look into the algorithm again, although my system is autonomous, so i guess Jordan Form will do, thank you for your insight.